# C format string when writing to file

Tags: c, printf

I'm having a bit of noob confusion how to use a formated string when writing to a file, and more in general I guess about `sprintf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    const char *exts = ".txt";
    char *saveToPath;

    sprintf(saveToPath, "/Path/To/My/File%s", exts);

    fp = fopen(saveToPath, "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
    fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I get a `segmentation fault` when trying the formatted saveToPath, but if I use a plain string `const char*` like "/Path/To/My/File.txt" it works.

Comment: You need room to store the path and `exts`, use `char saveToPath[100];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate memory to your saveToPath variable

e.g.

```
char saveToPath[100];
```

Also, consider using snprintf to avoid buffer overflows

e.g.

```
snprintf(saveToPath, 100 ,"/Path/To/My/File%s", exts);
```

So that you make sure you don't write anything beyond 100 bytes allocated for saveToPath

Answer (score 2):

`char *saveToPath` only declares a pointer to a `char`. It doesn't allocate any memory to save your characters.

You could either allocate memory on the stack:

```
char saveToPath[1024];
```

or you could allocate memory on the heap if you don't know at compile how much memory you would need:

```
char *saveToPath = malloc(nsize * sizeof *saveToPath);
```

Remember to check for buffer overflow before using `sprintf()`:

```
if(nsize < strlen("/Path/To/My/File") + strlen(exts) + 1)
    /* error - BUFFER NOT ENOUGH*/

sprintf(saveToPath, "/Path/To/My/File%s", exts);
```

You may use `snprintf()`, but remember it's non-standard and may come back to bite you in the back if you use it in a program intended to be portable.

Since you said you are inexperienced in `C`, I suggest you make it a habit to write portable code.

Comment: by `portable` you mean will work with other platforms? thanks

Comment: @JackBauer `snprintf()` is not available in C89 standard library. It only did become part of the standard in C99.

Answer (score 0):

you should pre-alloc memory for saveToPath; char saveToPath[100] pre-alloc 100 bytes in stack. However, for more safety and generic usage, I suggest you coding as follows:

```
const char *prefix = "/path/to/myfile";
const char *suffix = ".txt";
// here, 1 more bit for the terminal '\0'
char *saveToPath = (char *)calloc(sizeof(char), strlen(prefix) + strlen(suffix) + 1);
sprintf(saveToPath, "%s%s", prefix, suffix);
FILE *fp = fopen(...);
...
```

for more safety coding style, try to use snprintf instead of sprintf